# What does the ms-infopath in a url do?

Tags: infopath

If you have a link with a URL like

```
ms-infopath:ofe|u|https://myportal.sharepoint.com/site/someform/SOMEINFOPATHREF-220103C.xml
```

What does the prefix to the URL do?

Do all browsers understand this prefix or is it Microsoft specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix tells the browser to open the URL with Infopath, it allows the following to happen:

[image: opening a file with Infopath]

To the best of my knowledge you have to do this in Internet Explorer.